# Best way to use group by in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I am doing a group by on columns CARD_NO, MAX(EXPIRE_DATE) which contains 11,910,317 records in the table.

What is the best way I could get this done.
Below is the query which I used, but it takes quite a long time to return results.

```
SELECT CARD_NO,
 MAX(expire_date) EXPIRE_DATE
 FROM LCT_CARD_ISSUE11
 GROUP BY CARD_NO
```

Comment: There is no better way to do it. It takes a long time because there is a lot of data to scan. If you had an index on `CARD_NO` and `expire_date`, you might get very fast response, but it depends on the SQL optimizer, and adding an index is not free. Learning to tune Oracle SQL statements is a complex issue and there are entire books written on the subject.

Comment: @Andreas the dba has already added indexes on those columns.

Comment: I was talking about a single two-column index, not two different one-column indexes. But it may not matter much, depending on data distribution, i.e. how many records are there on average for each `CARD_NO`? How many columns are there on the table? As I already mentioned, tuning SQL is complex, since it depends on a lot of factors.

Comment: As @Andreas stated, query tuning is very complex and there are no blanket  answers, just a toolbox of things to try. So much depends on your data and the database itself (tablespace, memory, other loads). Depending on how volatile the data is, one thing that you could try is a materialized view. You may gain some performance by having the aggregation already done in the materialized view.

Comment: @Andreas even if it reduces the execution by a minute from , its a big achievement, so let me try with a two-column index btw do I keep the two different one-column indexes or remove it after creation of  two-column index

Comment: If your create an index on `CARD_NO, expire_date`, then an index on `CARD_NO` is redundant and should be dropped. Whether you still need an index on `expire_date` is impossible to say, without knowing all your queries. Remember to re-analyze the table with its new index.